# Dual graph relation to star-mesh duality

Tags: graph-theory, transformation, duality-theorems, planar-graphs

I'm confused about the realtionship between dual graphs and the so called star-mesh transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform.

Take a simple triangle, its dual graph looks like three lines meeting at a point (connected to another external point). The star-mesh duality tells us exactly that also, i.e. apply the transformation on a triangle and you'll get a 3 pointed star.

Now, if we take a a graph with 4 points that's maximally connected so that it has 6 edges (a tetrahedron), when we draw the dual graph it will look something like a butterfly (try it!).
However according to the star-mesh duality, a 4 pointed star is what is equivalent to a tetrahedral a graph.

[The star mesh duality for a triangle and tetrahedron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRkQz.png)

What exactly is going on here, do they just superficially seem related and can both things be true? The problem to me seems to be that for $N>3$ the star-mesh duality relates diagrams with different numbers of edges, whereas the dual diagram preserves the number of edges.

I have such a tetrahedral graph where the 6 edges are weighted, I wanted to use the star-mesh transform to find what the edges of the dual graph were (in terms of the original weights), but since this star-mesh duality doesn't seem to produce the dual graph I am not sure what one can use to do this.

Comment: There is no relationship between dual graphs and the star-mesh transform.

Comment: Do you mean [dual graph of a plane graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) here or some other kind of duality?

Comment: I mean the dual graph of a planar graph.